# How to fix "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:"

Tags: java, parsing

I'm trying to parse csv data in my java program, to make a program that can count fanout ratio and BFR. But when i trying to parse the csv file into my program it always said NumberFormaException.

the error show that something wrong in here.

```
int choice = input.nextInt();

if (choice == 1) {
    bfr1(coba1, coba2);
} else if (choice == 2) {
    bfr1(coba1, coba2);
} else {
    System.out.println("Not available!!!!");
}
```

and show error in line 97 here at int `pointer1 = Integer,parseInt(pointer)`

```
public static void bfr1(String s, List<String> l) {
    //split untuk pointer dan block size
    String[] splitSpasi = s.split(",");
    String pointer = splitSpasi[0].substring(0);
    int pointer1 = Integer.parseInt(pointer);

    //block size
    String blockS = splitSpasi[1].substring(1);
    int blockSn = Integer.parseInt(blockS);

    // Member
    String Member = l.get(0);
    String[] Membersp = Member.split("%");
    String[] MemberAngka = Membersp[1].split(",");
    String ukuranRecord_Member = MemberAngka[0].substring(1);
    int ukuranRecord_MemberIn = Integer.parseInt(ukuranRecord_Member);
    int bfrMember = blockSn/ukuranRecord_MemberIn;

    String keyP = MemberAngka[2].substring(1);
    int keyPin = Integer.parseInt(keyP);
    int hasilFanMember = blockSn/(pointer1+keyPin);

    System.out.println("BFR Member: " + bfrMember);
    System.out.println("Fanout Ratio Member: " + hasilFanMember);
}
```

i expect the output will be count the BFR and the fanout ratio

Comment: Could you post some sample data?

Comment: Have you tried printing the string that you pass to that particular Integer.parseInt call?

Comment: here's my csv file

```P8,B32768
Member,id_member,nama,telepon%R64,n1000,V8
Minjam,id_buku,id_member,dur_peminjaman%R64,n1000,V8
Buku,id_buku,judul,genre%R64,n1000,V8``` @devgianlu

Comment: `pointer` is `P8`, which is not a valid integer.